# Why does a constraint on linked planning entities cause the following score corruption exception?

Tags: kotlin, exception, optaplanner, timefold

I'm currently working on solving a VRP with pickups and deliveries. In the current model a `Vehicle` is my first `@PlanningEntity`, containing a `@PlanningListVariable` of `LoadJobs`, which can either be of type `PICKUP` or `DROPOFF`. Every `LoadJob` has the reference to the `Load` it is delivering and the `Load` class has references to both its `PICKUP` and `DROPOFF` `LoadJob`.

I've written the following constraint to ensure both `LoadJobs` are put onto the same `Vehicle` (of course, it would not make sense to try delivering a load that has never been picked up and it also would not make sense to pick up a load without ever delivering it):

```
fun pickupAndDropoffOnSameVehicle(constraintFactory: ConstraintFactory): Constraint {
    return constraintFactory
        .forEach(LoadJob::class.java)
        .filter { it.load.pickup.vehicle != it.load.dropoff.vehicle }
        .penalizeConfigurable()
        .asConstraint(PICKUP_AND_DROPOFF_ON_SAME_VEHICLE)
}
```

When I run in `FULL_ASSERT` mode, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Score corruption (100hard): the workingScore (-19init/-100hard/0medium/-11670soft) is not the uncorruptedScore (-19init/-200hard/0medium/-11670soft) after completedAction (LoadJob(id=DROPOFF-loDKrYTAqF5kIfjFM6n4) {null -> Vehicle(idx=0)[0]}):
Score corruption analysis:
  The corrupted scoreDirector has no ConstraintMatch(s) which are in excess.
  The corrupted scoreDirector has 1 ConstraintMatch(s) which are missing:
    com.cargonexx.vehiclerouting.solver.constraint/pickupAndDropoffOnSameVehicle/[LoadJob(id=PICKUP-loDKrYTAqF5kIfjFM6n4)]=-100hard/0medium/0soft
  Maybe there is a bug in the score constraints of those ConstraintMatch(s).
  Maybe a score constraint doesn't select all the entities it depends on, but finds some through a reference in a selected entity. This corrupts incremental score calculation, because the constraint is not re-evaluated if such a non-selected entity changes.
Shadow variable corruption in the corrupted scoreDirector:
  None
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.assertScoreFromScratch(AbstractScoreDirector.java:637)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.assertWorkingScoreFromScratch(AbstractScoreDirector.java:613)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.doAndProcessMove(AbstractScoreDirector.java:204)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.thread.MoveThreadRunner.run(MoveThreadRunner.java:131)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:577)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
```

Because of the error message, my guess is this might be caused by the transitive relation between two `LoadJobs` through the `Load` class. I've tried filtering for only `PICKUP`s before filtering for the same vehicle as well as joining `LoadJob::class.java`, then filtering for the same `Load` on both load jobs and only then filtering for the same vehicle, all to no avail.

What is the cause of this exception and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of how **incremental** score calculation interacts with

```
.filter { it.load.pickup.vehicle != it.load.dropoff.vehicle }
```

Neither `pickup` or `dropoff` are selected, so the ConstraintStreams implementation (regardless if it's OptaPlanner CS Drools impl, or Timefold's faster impl), doesn't know that when the pickup or dropoff's vehicle variable changes, this constraint needs to be re-evaluated (in a delta manner for scalability).

**Solution**

Something like:

```
fun pickupAndDropoffOnSameVehicle(constraintFactory: ConstraintFactory): Constraint {
    val pickupStream =
        constraintFactory.forEach(LoadJob::class.java).filter { it.type == LoadJobType.PICKUP }

    val dropoffStream =
        constraintFactory.forEach(LoadJob::class.java).filter { it.type == LoadJobType.DROPOFF }

    return pickupStream
        .join(dropoffStream, Joiners.equal { it.load.id })
        .filter { pickup, dropoff -> pickup.vehicle != dropoff.vehicle }
        .penalizeConfigurable()
        .asConstraint(PICKUP_AND_DROPOFF_ON_SAME_VEHICLE)
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer, that helped me a great deal! However, I don't really understand the underlying issue ("neither `pickup` or `dropoff` are selected"). From what I would have expected, the constraint should have been violated twice for each load not having pickup and dropoff on the same vehicle (once for the `PICKUP` loadJob and once for the `DROPOFF`). Either `it.load.pickup` or `it.load.dropoff` would always equal `it`. Could you elaborate why the planning entity wouldn't be selected? Or is it that the related planning entity isn't always selected together with the picked one?

Comment: For incremental score calculation, constraint streams only calculate the delta for each move. This allows Timefold to calculate 10k-500k scores per second, instead of a few hundred when scaling to large datasets. But for that to work, it needs to know which domain classes instances changed (which it does) and which constraints are affected by which domain class instances. The latter is done through `forEach(class)`, `join(class)` etc.

Comment: So when the `load` doesn't change, the constraint uses `load.pickup.vehicle` and the `pickup`changes, but the pickup was never forEach()ed or join()ed, it doesn't "see" the change, the delta is wrong and the score ends up corrupted.

Comment: Thank you, I think that clears it up for me +1

Comment: You're welcome :)