# Can a ProblemFact have a reference to a PlanningEntity?

Tags: kotlin, optimization, modeling, optaplanner, timefold

I currently have the following setup for solving a VRP with pickup and returns:

A `Vehicle` is a `PlanningEntity` and contains a `PlanningListVariable` of `LoadJob` instances (either `PICKUP` or `DROPOFF`):

```
@PlanningEntity
class Vehicle {
    @PlanningId lateinit var planningId: String

    @PlanningListVariable lateinit var tour: MutableList<LoadJob>
    
    // ...
}
```

A `LoadJob` is another `PlanningEntity`:

```
@PlanningEntity
class LoadJob {
    @PlanningId lateinit var id: String

    @InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "tour") //
    var vehicle: Vehicle? = null

    lateinit var location: Location
        private set

    lateinit var load: Load
        private set

    // ... more shadow variables and variable listener setup for arrival time follows
}
```

With our current setup, we are already able to handle multiple (sub-)tours on a single vehicle (we detect loops in the `PlanningListVariable`). Now, we would also like to be able to allow users to pin sub-tours on a vehicle. I know that optaplanner/timefold currently does not support variable pinning together with `PlanningListVariable`. I also know that refactoring the Model to use a chained planning variable could be an option. However, I suppose this could be more work than the approach I'm currently thinking of:

I could make the vehicle a planning fact by moving the `@PlanningListVariable` to a new `Tour` class:

```
@PlanningEntity
class Tour {
    @PlanningId lateinit var planningId: String

    @PlanningListVariable lateinit var tour: MutableList<LoadJob>

    lateinit var earliestStart: OffsetDateTime

    lateinit var latestEnd: OffsetDateTime

    lateinit var vehicle: Vehicle
    
    // ...
}
```

and simply reference the `Vehicle` from the `Tour` class.

I then could have constraints on `Tour` so `earliestStart` and `latestEnd` are respected when planning. This way, it should be possible to leave time slots for locked tours unassigned (and remove/add these tours in my transformation/persistence layer).

So my first and foremost question is: Is this a valid approach? Can optaplanner/timefold handle a model like this?

Followup questions:

1. If the answer to the first question is no, what would be a better approach?
2. If the answer to the first question is yes, is there an "ergonomic" way of grouping all tours on the same vehicle? I know I can use `groupBy` on a constraint stream - would this be the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that you're stretching the model to places where it hasn't been before - I can not give definitive answers to your question without trying it first; and I can not really try it without completely replicating this setup.

My recommendation would be to try your approach and report back what issues (if any) you ran into. We can then discuss if those issues are something we can/want to address.

The most generic answer to your original question is yes, though - technically, entities can be referenced from facts, just double-check that the cloners work properly. It may require sprinkling the code with `@DeepPlanningClone` here and there. (`FULL_ASSERT` environment mode for a few minutes should be enough to prove or disprove that.)

Comment: Hi, thank you (once again, kudos to you, Geoffrey and the rest of the Timefold team btw) for the helpful answer - the note on `@DeepPlanningClone` was the last puzzle piece I was missing. It was essential to mark the refactored `Vehicle` class with that.

Comment: Further note: The change in the model also required some changes to my constraints on the `Vehicle` class, so the solver would get notified about changes to the linked planning entities (instances of `Tour`) and wouldn't run into corrupted scores. A related question Geoffrey answered a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77482105/why-does-a-constraint-on-linked-planning-entities-cause-the-following-score-corr

Comment: Yes, once you get into these transitive relationships, the constraints need to be written in a specific way. I'm glad you were able to figure it out.

Comment: Just out of curiosity (and if the answer is no, maybe an improvement suggestion): Is it mentioned somewhere in the documentation that transitive relationships in Entities might require joining all Entity instances that influence a constraint match to avoid score corruption?

Comment: Maybe it's in the Javadoc, but most likely not in the user documentation. Pull requests are welcome. ;)